# Dynamic width to jqGrid column depending upon content with maximum width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid

I am using jqGrid with options autowidth : true and shrinkToFit: true and not specifying
width in colModel as my grid and its column are dynamic so I dont know which column to assign what width.
My problem is as I cant specify width to columns I want jqGrid to shrink column width according to max length content in that column so that other column can use that space.
I understand this might produce really big width for multi-line content,but I guess if there is option like max-width in colModel that will solve this issue as well.

in one line : can I have jqGrid with dynamic width columns where width will be calculated up content ?